# Is there a comma after and/or before though in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is there a comma after and/or before "though" in a sentence?

For example, I am talking about a method that is very slow. At the end of the paragraph I say:

> We will see in the following sections *though* there is a workaround to reduce the exponential explosion of the computational time.

Comment: I would rather use _although_ at the beginning of the sentence, or not use _though_ at all.

Comment: *That* after *though* is wrong. remove it, then the sentence makes sense.

Comment: Er, I think the "that" was needed (or is at least preferable). The "that" marker helps the reader parse the sentence correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, as we will see in the following sections, there is a workaround to reduce the exponential explosion of the computational time.

is, I think, a better way to express what you are trying to say.  If you wanted to use the word "though", I believe you would put commas both before and after the word.

Comment: I agree with you. However, I think I am overusing the word "however" in my document. I have to find some alternatives! Thanks

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: In your particular sentence you can simply drop the 'though' without any other changes. It is unnecessary.

Comment: I think that he wishes to have some way to express the word though, in it's meaning "despite the fact that".

Comment: You are both right. But my question served a double purpose, to know how to use though in this particular phrase and in other phrases in general. Maybe I was not precise enough...

Comment: We will see in the following sections, though, that there is a workaround to reduce the exponential explosion of the computational time.